# H - probe design in cylinder cavity

Tags: electromagnetism, design, measurement, resonance, probe

I give both a short description and a longer one below. Any advice on how to design two H-probes system in a cyinder is welcome and many thanks :)

## Short description

**Problem:** I wish to disign where to put two H-probes (H1, H2), and how big area (A1, A2), and length (l1, l2) they should have, to measure changes in a cylindrical cavity of height L, and radius R. I am a bit lost on how to do this optimally, and which equations governerns this design and would like some advices or directions on the topic. probes should be on the sides of the cylinder. Also if you have any tips or things to consider it is welcomed.

**Current solution:** By modelling the cavity for different resonant frequencies from different modes (TE_vpq, TM_vpq), and positioning the probes at where the peaks should be at. Length of probes is a quarter wavelength of the resonant frequencies. Area I have no idea really how to model it, found a master thesis showing an equation but else I don't know. Shape of probe I also don't know if it matters.

## Long description

### Problem

I'm trying to figure out how to optimally design two H-probes that can be used for the measurement of electromagnetic fields (microwaves) in a cylinder cavity with height L and radius R. I also have different sizes of cylinders, where the smallest one is L = 150 mm, R = 50 mm and the biggest is L ~= 1.5 m, R ~= 1/2 m. I wish to measure as many modes as possible (TM_vpq and TE_vpq), if possible. By optimal I mean I want to gather information from as many parts of the cavity as possible, and that it should be sensitive to content changes in the cavity (moisture and density mainly).

The probes will both excite and measure one at a time, like so:

```
Probe 1 excites a wave -> Probe 2 measures
Probe 2 excites a wave -> Probe 1 measures
```

So they will swap acting like an attenna or measuring probe. I am limited to two probes and if possible I wish them to be located on the sides of the cylinder, not the top or bottom.

[image]

### Current solution

My current suggestion, or idea of how to accomplish this, is to model the cavities without probes at the different resonant frequencies
$$
TM: f_{vpq} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}\sqrt{(\frac{X_{vp}}{r})^2 + (\frac{q\pi}{L})^2}
$$$$
TE: f_{vpq} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}\sqrt{(\frac{X_{vp}'}{r})^2 + (\frac{q\pi}{L})^2}
$$
The length, $l_1$, of one probe (say probe 1) should then be
$$l_1 = \frac{\lambda}{4}, \ \ \lambda = \frac{c}{f_{vpq}}\text{ is the wavelength of the frequency} $$
Then probe 2 should be put close to where the frequency mode has a peak in the cavity (found from modelling), and rotated either horisontal or vertical (I tried drawing it in the image above) depending on how the magnetic field 'moves' for the mode. Similarly probe 2's length $l_2$ can be designed for another frequency. This should assert good (hopefully) senstivity for at least two modes.

##### Literature

I have tried reading about it, and found articles where they implemented similar, but often they leave out the explanation on how the probe is designed, and why they put the probes at their specific location. I found this piece regarding a duplexer saying mostly the area only matters:

http://www.unixservice.com.au/hamradio/repeaters/duplexerchapters/5.html

and this

Design of a Cylindrical Cavity Resonator for Measurements of Electrical Properties of Dielectric Materials - Xiang Li, Yan Jiang, 2010
$$
\text{Area of probe} = \sqrt{\frac{R_c2\pi R (L + R)R_s}{2\pi f_{vpq}\mu}}
$$
where

- $R_s$ is the surface resistivity of the cavity resonator
- $R_C$ is the resistance for the cavity resonator
- $\mu$ is the permeability of the cavity resonator

Comment: What's a H-probe <-- question to the OP

Comment: Do you know how the H lines are "spacely" in that cylindar cavity?

Comment: @Andy aka.  A magnetic probe, or coupling loop. Example: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Cavity-excitation-using-a-loop-coupling-b-electric-probe-coupling-and-c-aperture_fig13_3089231

Comment: @Antonio51, Im not completely sure what you mean by 'spacely', if you mean how they 'curl' in the cylinder for their different modes, than yes it is quite well documented. for instance TE011 can be seen on this [image](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Distribution-of-a-magnetic-and-b-electric-field-lines-and-sample-location-inside-the_fig1_236114963)

Comment: Thanks also for quick answers, the answer rate of communities like this always amazes me :)

Comment: @Antonio51, Also modelling etc using elmer or FEnICS FEM solvers etc to gain more knowledge is possible, Im just not sure how to use this to design the probes.

Comment: Coupling magnetic probe sould be where H is max perpendiculary to the current "lines".

Comment: So, probe loop should be 'horizontally' placed. Coupling is max at center. EE&O.